# how to wait until a listener complete executing

Tags: android, kotlin

What I'm trying to do here is to add a download URL to an ArrayList inside a listener. Then println the ArrayList after all items have been added. However, since listeners are executed in an asynchronous way, println will always print an empty ArrayList. So, my question is how can I make it synchronized? meaning the println statement prints the ArrayList containing the items. Here's my code:

```
@Synchronized
    private fun postOfferNow() {
        val storageRef = storge.reference
        val images = ArrayList<String>()
        for (image in this. takenPicsPaths) {
            val file = Uri.fromFile(File(image))
            val ref = storageRef.child("Images/$offerOwnerID/${file.lastPathSegment}")
            ref.putFile(file).addOnFailureListener {

            }.addOnSuccessListener {
                ref.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener {
                    val url = it.result
                    images.add(url.toString()) //here is where I add items to images
                }
            }
        }
        println(images)// this will always print "[]"
    }
```

Comment: Which version your app running?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to that is to:
Check the images arrayList size after adding a URL to it, if it's with same size of items in takenPicsPaths, then you can start printing

But take in consideration that for this solution you must guarantee that all the items will be uploaded successfully in order to start printing after the last upload finishes.
If this is not guaranteed in your case, then declare an integer counter equal to 0 before the loop starts, add OnFailureListener after the onSuccess listener, and in both listeners you increment the counter.
Now wherever the counter reaches the wanted count, start printing.

And here i say 'Wherever' cuz you may reach the wanted count in the failure listener

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I actually want the println statement to be outside the listeners. Is there a way to make the program to wait until the listeners are done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can utilize coroutines, specifically wrapping your for loop into an async await.

```
private fun postOfferNow() {
   launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
       val result = async {
           ... for loop
           return images
       }.await()
       println(images)
    }
}
```

Edit: due to the callbacks you probably will have to utilize a suspendCancellableCoroutine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use coroutines.

Using `compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.1'`.

Your code will look something like this. (I wasn't sure what exceptions you wanted to catch or throw away, so I made educated guesses)

```
@Synchronized
private fun postOfferNow() {
    runBlocking {
        val storageRef = storge.reference
        val images = takenPicsPaths.map { image ->
            async {
                val file = Uri.fromFile(File(image))
                val ref = storageRef.child("Images/$offerOwnerID/${file.lastPathSegment}")
                runCatching { ref.putFile(file).await() }
                  .map { ref.downloadUrl.await().toString() }
                  .getOrNull()
            }
        }.mapNonNull { it.await() }
        println(images)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@Synchronized` annotation will only allow a single thread from you machine at a time from accessing the function which does not mean that the code following it will wait for the response of an *asynchronous call* which in your case is `ref.putFile(file)` and hence `println` is returning an empty array. There are two methods to resolve this:

**1).** Make a `println` call inside the `onSuccessListener` lambda or anything in general that has anything to do with the result of the *async* call should be written inside the listeners.

```
@Synchronized
    private fun postOfferNow() {
        val storageRef = storge.reference
        val images = ArrayList<String>()
        for (image in this. takenPicsPaths) {
            val file = Uri.fromFile(File(image))
            val ref = storageRef.child("Images/$offerOwnerID/${file.lastPathSegment}")
            ref.putFile(file).addOnFailureListener {

            }.addOnSuccessListener {
                ref.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener {
                    val url = it.result
                    images.add(url.toString()) //here is where I add items to images
                    println(images)  // this would work
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**2).** If you are familiar with *coroutines* then use *async/await*

```
launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    async {
    val response = await ref.putFile(file)
  }
}
```

Basically putting everything inside an *async* block and using *await* before every *async call*. You can learn more [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html#async-style-functions).

But I would highly discourage the latter method while dealing with **Firebase**, you should totally rely on the *listeners* provided by them.